# Better way than T.eye in theano

Tags: python, numpy, theano

The problem is, given a arbitrary 1-d vector `y`, expanded it into `d` basis vectors with `n` dimension.

The rule of the expansion is: each element in `y` is the index of columns in the n*n identity matrix.

For example:

```
 y = [3, 0, 1]
 n = 4
```

Since `n = 4`, we have the `4*4` identity matrix:

```
[1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Expand each element `y` using the rule, we have:

```
[0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0]
```

I want to solve this problem using theano, with very large `n` (>50k) and very long `y` (>10k), so efficiency is important.

The solution using numpy is trivial, but the numpy.eye function may cost too much, we may use anther method to make it faster. Comparing the following methods:

```
import numpy as np
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

n = 25500
y_value = np.asarray([2, 0, 10, 4], dtype='int32')

# method 1
%timeit np.eye(n)[y_value]  
# 10 loops, best of 3: 56.9 ms per loop

# method 2
def vec(i):
    e = np.zeros(n)
    e[i] = 1
    return e
%timeit np.vstack([vec(i) for i in y_value])  
# 100 loops, best of 3: 16.3 ms per loop
```

However, the second method may not work in theano since loop in symbolic variable may not trivial. Is there a method which can avoid using T.eye?

`y_value` can be an arbitrary 1-d vector.

Answer (score 1):

You can try another approach. In my computer:

```
>>> %timeit np.eye(n)[y_value]
1 loops, best of 3: 544 ms per loop
```

However, you don't need to create the whole array if you know in advance the rows you want. You can do this:

```
>>> n = 25500
>>> n_rows = y_value.size
>>> r = np.zeros((n_rows, n))
>>> r[range(n_rows), y_value] = 1
```

You create a way smaller array, only `y x n` where `y` is the size of your index vector, and populate it in every row. The timing in my computer is:

```
>>> %%timeit 
..: r = np.zeros((n_rows, n))
..: r[range(n_rows), y_value] = 1

100 loops, best of 3: 3.8 ms per loop
```

`x151` speedup in my laptop.

Additionally, if you don't want an array full of zeros at the rear (x-axis), you could do:

```
>>> %%timeit 
..: r = np.zeros((n_rows, y_value.max()+1))
..: r[range(n_rows), y_value] = 1

100000 loops, best of 3: 16 µs per loop
```

Which is even faster, but the resulting array is `y x ymax`, in this case `99 x 100`, which might not be what you want.